# Как внедрить Redis в схему MVC?

Tags: php, mvc, redis

Изначально проект работал только с базой данных, но теперь, в целях оптимизации, некоторые данные хранятся в Redis. Сам проект написан по схеме MVC. Как правильно внедрить Redis в эту схему?

Например, сейчас в одной из функций модели прописано:

```
...
if($is_redis){ //true
    $this->load->library("redis_library");
    $redis = $this->redis_library->connect();
    if($redis === false) $this->db_increment($timestamp, $field, $number); //Если не удалось подключиться к Redis - используем БД
    else $this->redis_increment($redis, $timestamp, $field, $number); //Используем Redis
} else $this->db_increment($timestamp, $field, $number); //Используем БД
```

Но есть подозрения что так делать неправильно. То-есть если появится еще какое-то хранилище данных, например Memcached, то придется проверять еще и на него.

Хочется разбить обработку этих СУБД на разные модели, но правильно ли это? Как я понимаю модель в концепции отвечает за одну таблицу в БД. Но в NO-SQL нет понятия таблиц. Есть просто несколько баз данных. Что можете посоветовать?

Comment: модель вообще ни каким местом не должна быть привязана к бд

Comment: Ну, можно использовать ооп. сделать интерфейс и две имплементации, для редиса и для бд. И использовать инстанс нужного классу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых, я бы сделал акцент на том, что Redis и memcached в первую очередь хранилища типа "ключ-значение". Для контраста: у таких NoSQL СУБД, как MongoDB и т.п., есть понятие коллекций и документов, что намного ближе к реляционным таблицам и кортежам, а значит потенциально могут быть отражены в моделях.

Как правило, Redis и memcached используются для кеширования, потому что хранят данные в ОЗУ, а кеш можно в любой момент безопасно почистить. И хотя у Redis есть механизм скидывания дампа на диск, это не превращает его в основное хранилище данных, а лишь позволяет снизить время прогревания кеша после перезагрузки.
Все основные данные должны храниться в надежном месте, например, в основной базе. Или в файловом хранилище. Или еще где-то, изначально рассчитанное на долговременное хранение.

Во вторых, нужно определиться, для чего именно вы хотите использовать Redis. Т.е. в частности, какими критериями обладают хранимые данные.

Возьмем пример от балды. Интернет-магазин, в нем есть товары, разложенные по категориям с фильтрами, а к каждому товару можно писать комментарии.
Описание товара, его характеристики, изображение, а так же комментарии к нему должны находиться в соответствующих таблицах основной БД. Это очевидно. А вот в кеш (в Redis, например), можно положить:

- результат запроса в БД для каталога, фасеточного фильтра, поиска (кеширование на уровне QueryBuilder'a);
- сериализованные модели (кеширование на уровне ORM);
- посчитанные счетчики количества комментариев к товару, кол-ва товаров в категории (кешиирование на уровне шаблона);
- и т.п.

На худой конец туда можно положить готовый рендер карточки товара, каталога или чего-то подобное.

Главный вопрос, который придется решить - это инвалидация кеша. Нужно будет придумать механизм, как сбросить/пересчитать кеш.

Например, при добавлении нового комментария, можно в тупую сбросить счетчик количества комментариев в кеше, тогда при следующем запросе cache mismatch (непопадание в кеш) должно вызвать подсчет кол-ва комментариев запросом в базу и сохранить результат в кеш.

А вот с фасеточными фильтрами может быть сложнее. По идее нужно сбросить/пересчитать кеш только для тех фильтров, которые в результатах содержат конкретный товар.

В любом случае, возможно вам стоит обратить внимание на подход, именуемый [CQRS](https://habr.com/ru/post/347908/), но в целом это может оказаться сложнее и не ответит на ваш вопрос.